# laravel artisan::queue fails but not in console

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

Hi I have a very simple console command that copies some images,

Using the following console comand works with no problem

```
 php artisan revo:copyPhotos baseTenant destination
```

However when calling this from php code with `artisan::queue` it fails

I get this error in the failed_jobs table

```
{"job":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\QueuedJob","data":["revo:copyPhotos",{"origin":"baseTenant","destination":"testArtisan"}]}
```

And I'm calling it this way from `php`

```
Artisan::queue('revo:copyPhotos', ['origin' => 'baseTenant', 'destination' => 'testArtisan']);
```

The command signature:

```
protected $signature = 'revo:copyPhotos
                        {origin         : The tenant name of the origin account}
                        {destination    : the new account to be created as copy of origin}
                        ';
```

I'm using queues with beanstalkd and other queue jobs work without any problem (extending `job` not `command`),

Any idea if I'm missing anything? nothing appears on the `storage/logs` file for that failed job..

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found I needed to call

`php artisan queue:restart`

So the queue deamon got aware of the new code